# Не находит файл в папке "No such file or directory" VS Code

Tags: python, файлы, visual-studio-code

Не находит файл в папке, хотя в папке файл есть. Вопрос именно в VS Code(проверял в sublime все работает). Как мне кажется проблема в том что VS Code не может правильно прочесть путь.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

```
C:\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\╨╡╨╜╨╕╤Б\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

'c:\Users\╨╡╨╜╨╕╤Б
```

Comment: Вангую, что в тех кракозябрах написано `енис` :D `print('╨╡╨╜╨╕╤Б'.encode('cp866').decode('utf-8'))`. Т.е. получили байты в cp866 (кодировка терминала винды) и попытались как строку в utf-8 раскодировать. В принципе, советую имя пользователя/компьютера держать в латинице.

Comment: Все верно, но как это исправить? Просто переименовать папку?

Comment: @dog3000 просто переименовать нельзя. Не загрузите профиль потом.

Comment: Попробуйте так https://ichip.ru/sovety/windows-10-kak-izmenit-imya-polzovatelya-203072, но есть вероятность что что-нибудь сломается

Comment: Благодарю, за комментарии, попробую поискать решение.